# Defering drag & drop events to the container (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have a basic winforms MDI application working as multi document editor.

**Whats working**

- With no documents open, dragging a file from explorer into the
  client area fires the containers drag drop events as expected.
- If a document is open that does not indicate it supports drag drop,
  then dragging a file from explorer onto it also fires the containers
  drag drop events.

**Whats NOT working**

- If I have a document open that supports drag drop, then it gets the
  drag drop events when a file is dragged onto it. This is expected,
  and required as the document makes used of dragging. However for some
  data types (specfically when a file is dragged) I still want the
  parent to handle it.

Basically I need a way to selectivley defer the drag drop events to the parent container.

A basic sample app can be downloaded here.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0iefczgq6bqmgwg/7F-SfeJLBL/Code/DragDropTest.zip

Essentially want I want to do is

```
    private void EditorControl_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(this.Name + " DragEnter");

        // if we know about the data being dragged 
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("MyData"))
        {
            // control specific drag handler
        }
        else
        {
            // we don't know how to deal with the drop data so
            // pass the event to the parent form/control
            this.ParentForm.FireDragEnter();
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Post your DragEnter event handler code.

Comment: I've never been great with drag & drop, but I thought you could set `e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None` to selectively disable dropping (which, theoretically, would allow a parent control to accept the drop).

Comment: Setting e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None just means the cursor becomes the not allowed action cursor. The events are still only passed to the control being dragged over.